# TNSNames.ora error

Tags: oracle, vb6, oracle11g

```
Set OraDatabase1 = OraSession.DbOpenDatabase(strLocation, "test/test_test", 0&)
```

I am trying to connect my oracle from my VB applicaton.

I have Oracle 9i and Oracle 11g installed in my computer.

I have problem in connecting in. I am getting tnsnams.ora error.

Comment: Seriously?? Shoudn't you know how to post a reasonable question???  WHere is all the supporting info?  What is the error?  What db library are you using ado, ado.net, etc?  What have you tried?  Can you connect from a command line prompt using sqlplus?

Comment: create the appropriate entry in tnsnames.ora for test/test_test

Answer (score 0):

You need the "test/test_test" entry in your tnsnames.ora file. This file is typically found in the oracle install DIR under (ORACLE_VERSION)/NETWORK/ADMIN/ folder